# How can I copy file using windows variable path with vbscript under elevated privillege?

Tags: windows, vbscript

Please I would like to know how I can copy files in windows using windows variable path with vbscript under elevated privillege. I have tried the codes below but it's not working.

```
dim filesys
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FileExists("%AppData%\file.exe") Then
filesys.CopyFile "%AppData%\file.exe", "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
End If
```

```
Dim objFso, strSourcePath, strDestPath
strSourcePath = "%AppData%\file.exe"
strDestPath = "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFso.FileExists(strSourcePath) then
    objFso.CopyFile strSourcePath, strDestPath, True
End If
Set objFso = Nothing
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: I check the file directory and I discovered the files weren't pesent after running the vbs script more so I use an ultrasearch software to search for the file by date, I didn't find it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dim filesys, WshShell
set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
If filesys.FileExists(WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "\file.exe") Then
filesys.CopyFile WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "\file.exe", WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you wasif, you code worked for me. What if I can to copy to drive and netwofk folder? What will the code look like? Can you please help me about this as well?

Comment: Just add a `, True` at the end of `filesys.copyfile` method and changes file paths to unc file path. Please accept the answer by clicking the big tick mark. Thank you for being helped by me!

Comment: I am still confused, please an you provide me code on that can:
Copy files ["*.exe","*.vbs"] and folders ["folder1", "folder2"] from any windows location to windows Variable path like; [%AppData%,%Tmp%], Drive path like ["c:\","d:\"] with hidden file attribute?

Comment: `filesys.copyfile "//server/share/source", "//server/share/destination", True`

Comment: Did you mean I can make it this way for example to copy file:
dim filesys, WshShell
set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
If filesys.FileExists(WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "\*.fileextensionA", "\*.fileextensionB","\*.fileextensionC") Then
filesys.CopyFile WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "\*.fileextensionA", "\*.fileextensionB","\*.fileextensionC", WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
End If

Comment: You can't use multiple wildcards at a time. *Also this discussion is getting longer. As you are new here, you may not know questions cannot be extended after the original. Try asking a new question there more community members can help you.*

Comment: And also I can make it this way for example to copy folder: dim filesys, WshShell set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") If filesys.FileExists(WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "c:\source1","c:\source2") Then filesys.CopyFile WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "c:\source1","c:\source2", WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\" End If

Comment: Yes that way works.

Comment: Wasif, WHat if I would like to copy more than one fie type from more than one location?

Comment: I tried the code below but its not working:
dim filesys, WshShell
set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
If filesys.FileExists(WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%HomePath%") & "\Local\Temp\*.tmp") Then
filesys.CopyFile WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%HomePath%") & "\Local\Temp\*.tmp", WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "\Filebkp\"
End If